# How to extract a parsed email address from a LinkedIn API response?

Tags: javascript, auth0, linkedin-api

I'm trying to setup a custom Auth0 LinkedIn Connection.

This is what I have for the Fetch User Profile Script:

```
function fetchUserProfile(accessToken, context, callback) {

  //Create the profile object
  const profile = {
    user_id: '',
    given_name: '',
    family_name: '',
    email: '',
  };

  // Call the Linkedin Primary Contact API
  request.get(
    {
      url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      }
    },
    (err, resp, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
        return callback(new Error(body));
      }

      let bodyParsed;
      try {
        bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
      } catch (jsonError) {
        return callback(new Error(body));
      }

      profile.user_id = bodyParsed.id;
      profile.given_name = bodyParsed.localizedFirstName;
      profile.family_name = bodyParsed.localizedLastName;

    }
  );
  
  // Call the Linkedin Profile API
  request.get(
    {
      url: 'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/clientAwareMemberHandles?q=members&projection=(elements*(primary,type,handle~))',
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken,
      }
    },
    (err, resp, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return callback(err);
      }

      if (resp.statusCode !== 200) {
        return callback(new Error(body));
      }

      let bodyParsed;
      try {
        bodyParsed = JSON.parse(body);
      } catch (jsonError) {
        return callback(new Error(body));
      }
    console.log(body);
    profile.email = bodyParsed.elements.handle~.emailAddress;

    }
  );

  //Send the profile object to the callback
  callback(null, profile);

}
```

It works (almost) but I'm having trouble putting `emailAddress` into the `profile` object.

The `console.log(body);` returns something like this (email redacted):

```
{
   "elements":[
      {
         "handle":"urn:li:emailAddress:102319820",
         "type":"EMAIL",
         "handle~":{
            "emailAddress":"REDACTED@gmail.com"
         },
         "primary":true
      }
   ]
}
```

The problem is that `profile.email = bodyParsed.elements.handle~.emailAddress;` gives an error because it uses the `~` symbol.

So how do I access `emailAddress` and insert it into the `profile` object?

Comment: bodyParsed.elements[0]["handle~"].emailAddress.  But i would use map, since elements is array

Comment: @Nonik Can you elaborate on "But i would use map, since elements is array" with some code? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: does this answer your question? https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp

Comment: Not really sorry :/

Comment: map creates a new array with the results of calling a function for every array element. Because elements is an array, there is a possibility you can get multiple emails. so bodyParsed.elements.map(i=>i["handle~"].emailAddress will return an array of email addresses. This is safer then accessing by index, because if elements would be empty array elements[0] will produce error.

Comment: I'm leaning map() for the first time. Have been reading up on it and I understand how it works now. I get that `bodyParsed.elements.map(i=>i["handle~"].emailAddress)` will return an array of emails. But I still need to access the first value of the array so it therefore becomes `bodyParsed.elements.map(i=>i["handle~"].emailAddress)[0]`. I don't understand how that is safer? Won't it still give an error if empty?

Comment: no, you need to check result length and then if array not empty get by index, and also handle empty scenario